# Recursively delete all .exe files with the same name as the containing folder

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I want to delete all .exe files in the current folder and all the sub-folders.

I read that `find . -name "*.exe" -exec rm -f '{}' \;` will do, but I want to do the delete only if the container folder has the same name as the .exe.

Example:

```
/me/folder1/folder1.exe    - delete folder1.exe
/me/folder 2/folder 2.exe  - delete 'folder 2.exe'
/me/folder3/otherexe.exe   - do not delete otherexe.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

Run this in Bash. It iterates over all `.exe` files and compares the parent directory name against the filename (without extension).

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in **/*.exe; do
    dir="$(basename "$(dirname "$f")")"  # get dirname
    file="$(basename "${f%.*}")"         # get filename, without extension
    if [ "$dir" = "$file" ]; then
        rm -i -- "$f"
    fi
done
```

The trick to get the raw directory name is to call `basename` on the `dirname` of the file.
All substitutions need to be quoted though to make this command work with file names containing whitespace.

If you do not want to be prompted before removing files, remove the `-i` option for the `rm` call.

Comment: Sorry, but shall I save it in a file then run, or just copy/paste on the terminal?

Comment: You can just copy-paste this entire piece of code from your current working directory. You can, of course, also save it in a shell script, but that's not really needed.